# In-App Purchase: "This is not a Test User Account"

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an app that uses In-App Purchases, but when I tap on buy and enter my Apple ID and password I get this error:

> This is not a Test User account. Please create a new account in the
>   Sandbox environment.  [Environment: SandBox]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use your Apple ID for testing the In-App purchase.
You need to create a test user (with different email id) in the [itunes connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa) for testing the in-app purchase.

1. Go to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa)
2. Login with your credentials
3. Choose manage Users
   [image: Choose Manage]
   4> Select Test User
   [image]

Comment: thanks for the reply but when I try to create a new user it asks for my credit card info.

Comment: you need to create a test user in the itunes connect

Comment: @JohandeKlerk: please check the images :)

Comment: @JohandeKlerk: still have issues ?

Comment: @JohandeKlerk: with pleasure :)

Comment: In the redesigned iTunes Connect there's now a "Sandbox Testers" tab at the top of the Users and Roles page. Accounts created using the first tab - even if they have the "In-App Purchase" credential, do not work with the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

1. For testing the in app purchase in development phase you need to
   create the test user in the sand box environment ,  For walk through
   use this link

   [1]: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases