# the apple id you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am debugging my in-app purchase on ipad ( ios 7.0.3).

But when I enter my password, it always says "the apple id you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect".

1. my developer id and the apple id registered on this ipad are different.
2. when I intentionally enter wrong password, it displays a different message "Your Apple ID or password is incorrect".
3. My in-app purchase is in review state. But I feel, it doesn't have any impact on sandbox testing
4. I have restarted my device. I can use the same password for downloading/purchasing other apps from itunes.

I am not posting my in-app purchase code as this is out of our coding context.

Comment: Did you add test user account ? If no please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320710/in-app-purchase-this-is-not-a-test-user-account

Answer (score 8):

In order to test in-app purchases before they are approved, you have to use test users, which you can create in iTunes Connect.

Once you sign in to iTunes Connect, you click where it says "Manage Users", which will let you create test users. Once you create a test user, you can use it within your development build of your app to test your in-app purchases. You can also create multiple test users if you need to repeatedly test non-consumable in-app purchases.

Comment: I am getting the same error after creating a test user too. Any idea why? I have also signed out the signed in user in device setting and I am testing it on a real device.

Comment: If you enter a valid Apple Id on test IAP, you  should first receive usual confirmation alert (with price mentioned), and then the following alert:
`You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time`

Comment: This is weird I am getting this too. created a test user followed all the steps didnt sign into account on my device just when promted by testing the app. I get "The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was inccorect. please try again" when i put in the wrong password i get this message "You Apple ID or password is incorrect"

Comment: did anyone solve this issue? I have just created a test account and still the the stupid "The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect. Please try again." ... I find this process very unfriendly to set up and get working!!!

Comment: Bump! Same issue here.

Comment: I still get this error/warning even though my application has been approved but it is in the state "Pending Developer Release". Does the application need to be "fully" released to test a production itunes purchase?

Answer (score 0):

we have had same issue, spent whole day chasing rabbit at the end what solved issue was to set test account App Store Territory/country **United states**, in our case we have set country Pakistan on test account user causing issue

Answer (score 0):

We also recently experienced this issue.

We "solved" it by using shorter email addresses for test users.

Emails longer than about 25 characters seemed to cause the error.