# Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect, Pending Developer Release

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes

This question has been partially answered here: [the apple id you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207208/the-apple-id-you-entered-couldnt-be-found-or-your-password-was-incorrect)

My application has been approved (along with the in-app Product) and is "Pending Developer Release" (I configured 'Version Release' to 'Manually release this version' so that I can test the auto-renew subscription model with a real itunes account).

Can I test in-app purchases with a production iTunes account with an application in the release state of "Pending Developer Release".

Comment: Lovely, i get a -1. Explain or direct me to the answer then.

Comment: No you can't...You need to release the app in order to test it with production iTunes account. You can test it through TestFlight but still it will be in Sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. :)

Best you can do is use a TestFlight build but that still validates against sandbox only.